# How to Eval a value in my config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, detailsview

I have the following case:

I store a specific path in my web.config file like this:

```
<add key="pdfPath" value="domainName/aa/pdf/"/>
```

and I want to `eval` this value in my hyperlink in my `DetailsView`:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pdf file">
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hl_link" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("thevaluefromConfigfile")%>'><%#Eval("filename") %></asp:HyperLink>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

1. How do I read the value from my configuration file?
2. I want this link to open in a new window. Is the hyperlink the best
   choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a A tag instead

```
<a id="hl_link" target="_blank" 
href='<%#ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["pdfPath"]%>'><%#Eval("filename") %></a>
```

how to read the key:

```
 ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["pdfPath"];
```

Comment: good but the first question, how to `eval` the value of config file?

Answer (score 4):

Check this code

Replace

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hl_link" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("thevaluefromConfigfile")%>'><%#Eval("filename") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

With

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hl_link" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%$ AppSettings:thevaluefromConfigfile %>'><%$ AppSettings:filename %></asp:HyperLink>
```

Is it possible for you to use anchor tag? If yes then use that one it will navigate you on separate new window, while you can also use window.open() function in navigateURL to open new window. For further information check this [link](http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2009/01/open-new-window-in-aspnet-web-page_28.html) and also this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/coltk/archive/2003/04/30/6221.aspx).

Comment: This is the better solution if you need to pull a value from appsettings inside an attribute of a server control.

Comment: Thanks jm2 for your appreciation.

Comment: No worries Just_name. You can mark my answer tick if you found answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<%$ AppSettings:pdfPath %>`

Answer (score 2):

probably you should replace:

```
<%#Eval("thevaluefromConfigfile")%>
```

with something like this:

```
<%# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pdfPath"] %>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,what about the second part of question . in a new window?

Comment: add TARGET="_blank" to your link